# Django APIView to log out of a user session

Tags: python, django, session, django-rest-framework

I have a Django module which is called from an SSO service. The service has a single signout function which makes a single `GET` request to a URL given to it during login.

I'm trying to set up an `APIView` in Django to handle this logout. The origin service never checks the response; it only calls the `GET` URL once.

I'm trying something like this for the `APIView` but keep getting `session.DoesNotExist` exceptions:

```
class LogoutApi(APIView):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        s = Session.objects.get(session_key=kwargs.get('sk', ''))
        s.delete()
        return Response({'result': True})
```

I know I have a valid session but even when I try iterating through the `Session.objects` I can't find it.

I also tried pulling the key from the `SessionStore`:

```
class LogoutApi(APIView):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        sk = request.GET.get('sk', '')
        try:
            s = SessionStore(sk)
            del s[sk]
            return Response({'result': True})
        except:
            self.logger.error(sys.exc_info()[0])
        return Response({'result': False})
```

It still wasn't successful. Is there a way I can set up a `GET` API call to terminate a specific session?

Comment: Do you have the session middleware active in the `MIDDLEWARE` setting? or do you create the session somehow at login?

Comment: I do have `django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware` active in my middleware list.

Comment: well that's weird, if you have the middleware when you login a Session object should be created. Try to debug the session middleware code and see what key is used to create the session.

Comment: Are you sure you have a session? Session isn't created when you login through API endpoint. Token-based authentication is stateless. Session-based authentication is used when you login to API with your browser, for example. How do you login?

Comment: The user logs in through the SSO site. They then open a page which uses OAuth to login to the Django site. I store a bunch of values at that login time into the user's session `self.request.session['user_name'] = request.GET.get('user_name', None)`. That's the session data I'm trying to clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the issue was that the session engine was set to use signed cookies. After I removed the following line from my configuration, all worked as expected:

```
SESSION_ENGINE = "django.contrib.sessions.backends.signed_cookies" # Removed this line
```

For reference, this is the logout code that worked with the above setting:

```
class LogoutApi(APIView):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        sk = request.GET.get('sk', '')
        if sk:
            s = SessionStore(session_key=sk)
            s.delete()
            return Response({'result': True})
        return Response({'result': False})
```